# How to know if a particular application is installed or not on the device?

Tags: android

I want to check whether an app is installed on the device or not. I am using code below :

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        if (packageInfoList != null) {
            for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packageInfoList) {
                Log.d(TAG, "-->"+packageInfo.packageName);
                String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
                if (packageName != null && packageName.equals(uri)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Which gives me all the packages but not the one that I except.
I am trying to find this app : rootcloak and exposed installer
Not able to find these apps with the code above.

Comment: If it returns false that means your app is not install in device which you mention in uri.

Comment: Hi, have a look at my answer. It will return a boolean according to application exist on your device. Just pass the package name and app_name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: @RonakThakkar Let me check

Comment: ok, let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: @RonakThakkar It didnt work. I am trying to find RootCloak app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696617/5726464)

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = 
context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : pkgAppsList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "__<>"+resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName != null 
                    && resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equals(uri)) {
              return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
```

This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

**Use Below Code:**

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(String package_name, String app_name)
{
    try {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("" + package_name, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        return true;

    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device has not installed " + app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Call the method like:**

```
isAppInstalled("com.whatsapp", "Whatsapp"); // it will return true if your device is having whatsApp.

isAppInstalled("com.randomname", "anyname"); //it will return false
```

Comment: I am not getting any error, its just that PackageManager dont have that package.

Comment: Thank you for the support. Keep rocking

Answer (score 1):

like whatsapp

shareImage("com.whatsapp", "Whatsapp");

call

```
public void shareImage(String pkgname, String appname) {
  String path = null;
  try {
    path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
    arrImagePath.get(slidePager.getCurrentItem()), "Title", null);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  share.setPackage(pkgname);
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
  share.setType("image/*");
  share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image File");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check using application id of particular app
for example
check

getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);

return true;

else
  false

check this answer it may helpful to you.
[How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)